# Get URL redirects with slimerJS and take screenshot of final URL

Tags: javascript, redirect, phantomjs, headless-browser, slimerjs

How can I get all the URL redirects in slimerJS and save them into an array then render a screenshot of the final URL.

For example if I run red.com through slimer but it redirects through php to blue.com which then redirects again to yellow.com through javascript, how can I save these redirects into an array?

Once the redirecting has finished I would then take a screenshot of the final URL, so yellow.com in the example above.

I'm using slimer 1.0 because I want to use slimer in headless mode.

Here's some simplified code I wrote over the weekend.

```
call to slimer (windows)
./slimerjs/src/slimerjs.bat --headless slimer-redirects.js http://google.com
```

The call to google.com using the script below doesn't pick up the redirect to google.co.uk (I'm in UK).
Strangely though the code below does detect javascript redirects.
Another problem with the code below is it doesn't seem to pick up multiple i.e > 2 redirects when it does work.

```
var system = require("system");
var page;
var myurl = system.args[1];

var renderPage = function(url) {
    page = require('webpage').create();
    page.onNavigationRequested = function(url, type, willNavigate, main) {
        if (url != myurl) {
            myurl = url;
            // page.close(); // makes some redirects hang. google.com for example

            setTimeout('renderPage(myurl)', 1);
        }
    };
     page.open(myurl)
    .then(function (status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            // I would then render screenshot here and exit
            console.log("Final URL is: " + myurl);
            slimer.exit();
        }

    });

};

renderPage(myurl);
```

It seems quite a simple task to just get the redirect URL's but I can't figure it out.
If it's not possible with slimer I would also like to know of other options. Chrome headless with or without puppeteer maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback [onUrlChanged()](https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/api/webpage.html#webpage-onurlchanged) for saving redirect URL

```
var urls = [];
page.onUrlChanged = function(url) {
    urls.push(url);
};
```

This snippet should help you